# Stock index data from Bloomberg using request and bs4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to scrape stock Index data from this site 'https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/stocks' and save the values in a .CSV file.

This is my code so far:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen('https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/stocks')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

for siblings in bs.find('tbody',{'class':'data-table-body'}).tr.next_siblings:
    print(siblings)
```

I get the data i need from this code, but i want to clean the HTML to only show the name of index and relevant values. The header in the CSV file should be:

**Name  Value   Net Change  % Change    1 Month     1 Year  Time (EDT**)

Thank you in advance for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scraping I suggest you to check out [requests-html](https://html.python-requests.org/) library (only Python 3.6 supported), since BeautifulSoup API can be a bit cumbersome and unintuitive. Requests-HTML uses BeautifulSoup under the hood but provides a lot of handy methods that can simplify your code. Here is the implementation of your task with requests-html:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

HEADERS = ("Name", "Value", "Net Change", "% Change" "1 Month", "1 Year", "Time (EDT)")

session = HTMLSession()

response = session.get('https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/stocks')
tables = response.html.find('tbody.data-table-body')

rows = []
for table in tables:
    for tr in table.find('tr'):
        row = []
        for header, td in zip(HEADERS, tr.find('td')):
            content = td.full_text.strip()
            row.append((header, content))
        rows.append(row)

for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Thank you Denis. Unfortunately i am working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it seems to be problematic to install python 3.6, pipenv and requests-html library

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/stocks'
headers = ('Name', 'Value', 'Net Change', '% Change' '1 Month', '1 Year', 'Time (EDT)')

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

trs = soup.select('.data-table-body > tr')


with open('data.csv', 'w') as outcsv:
    writer = csv.writer(outcsv)
    writer.writerow(headers)

    for tr in trs:
        tds = tr.find_all('td')[:7]
        tds[0].select_one('[data-type="abbreviation"]').decompose()  # optional

        content = [td.text.strip() for td in tds]
        writer.writerow(content)
```

If you want to store both the abbreviation and the full name, e.g.: `INDU:IND   DOW JONES INDUS. AVG` delete the line marked as optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like the following to get the data and write it accordingly.

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Headers = ["Name", "Value", "Net Change", "% Change", "1 Month", "1 Year", "Time (EDT)"]

res = urlopen('https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/stocks')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.read(),'html.parser')

with open('bloomberg.csv','w', newline='') as infile:
    writer = csv.writer(infile)
    writer.writerow(Headers)
    for tr in soup.select(".data-table-body tr"):
        data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in tr.find_all("td")]
        writer.writerow(data)
```